# Add extra field on items of <v-data-table>

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuex, vuetify.js

I have `medications` object as follow:

```
medications: [
     {
        'name': 'abc',
        'id': naks23kn,
        'resident': //this is resident id, resident is another object
         .........
     },
     {.......},.....
     ]
```

I wanted to add another field `residentName` on this object list or is there any way so that I can display 'residentName' in the `v-data-table` ?:

```
 medications: [
     {
        'name': 'abc',
        'id': naks23kn,
        'resident': //this is resident id, resident is another object
        'residentName': 'ad' //set this new field
         .........
     },
     {.......},.....
     ]
```

I am using `v-data-table> as :

```
<v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="medications"
      :items-per-page="20"
      :search="search"
      class="elevation-23"
    >
```

Now I want to add an `residentName` field based on the `resident` field. For this I did the following:

```
export default {
    data() {
        return {
           medications: [],
        }
    },
     computed: {
      ...mapGetters([
        'allMedications', //this is used to get all medication from medication store
        'getResidentsById',
      ]),
    },
    created() {
       this.get_resident_list(),
       this.get_registered_medication_list();
    },
    methods: {
      ...mapActions([
        'get_registered_medication_list', //this is used to call API and set state for medication
        'get_resident_list', //this is used to callAPI and set state for resident
      ]),
      getResidentName(id) {
        const resident = this.getResidentsById(id)
        return resident && resident.fullName
      },
    },
   watch: {
     allMedications: {
      handler: function () {
        const medicationArray = this.allMedications;
        console.log("Created this");
        this.medications = medicationArray.map(medication => ({
            ...medication,
            residentName: this.getResidentName(medication.resident)
        })
        );
      },
      immediate: true
      },
    }
 }
```

In `header`

`headers: [
     { text: 'Medication Name', value: 'name' },
     { text: 'Resident', value: 'residentName' },
  ]`

This is in `resident.js` getter module

```
getResidentsById: (state) => (id) => {
        return state.residents.find(resident => resident.id === id)
    }
```

Edit: This is working, i.e I am getting `residentName` when the page is created but if I refresh the page then I get `residentName=undefined`

Comment: add it to `headers`

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I have `headers: [{ text: 'Resident', value: 'residentName' },], Do you mean call function on this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` to add new prop to your each item in array

```js
let medications = [{
  name: 'abc',
  id: 'naks23kn',
  resident: 1
}]

medications.map(item => item.residentName = "Your Resident Name")
console.log(medications)
```

This should work

```
watch: {
  allMedications: {
    handler: function() {
      const medicationArray = this.allMedications;
      console.log("Created this");
      this.medications = medicationArray.map(medication => medication.residentName = this.getResidentName(medication.resident)));
    },
    immediate: true
  },
}
```

Comment: Where do I put the map function i.e `medications.map(item => item.residentName = "Your Resident Name")`? In watch, created or method ?

Comment: Where do you fetch `medication` data from ? Is there any action in your store ?

Comment: I have called form and set using watch **getter-allMedication** and on `watch: { allMedication() {this.medications = this.allMedication;}}`

Comment: Using my method above, it is being set only when I change anything on watch method and reload the server, it is not being set from the time the component is  created. I want the **residentName** to be set from the time when the component is being created.

Comment: This is working but if I refresh the page the value is not being set. `residentName=undefined`